# Messed up my LIBRARY_PATH for bash, using OSX

Tags: macos, bash, environment-variables

I am quite the novice and I messed something up awhile back. I do not know what I did, but now whenever I start up a new terminal I constantly have to `export LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/local/lib`. This is the default path for OSX I thought, and I think I might have voided it somehow.

It has just become so annoying to type that every time I want to run something like a gsl library, where are the default paths for bash on osx set? Thanks for any help you can offer.

Comment: `LIBRARY_PATH` or `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`?

Comment: `/opt/local/lib` is *not* in the default library path for Mac OS X. I'm not sure it's a default anywhere. Maybe you're thinking of `/usr/local/lib`? See the [dyld(1)](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/dyld.1.html) and [dlopen(3)](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/dlopen.3.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/3/dlopen) for the details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add it to `~/.bash_profile`

[§ Invocation](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash)

```
When bash is invoked as an interactive login shell, or as a non-interactive shell
with the --login option, it first reads and executes commands from the file 
/etc/profile, if that file exists. After reading that file, it looks for 
~/.bash_profile, ~/.bash_login, and ~/.profile, in that order, and reads and 
executes commands from the first one that exists and is readable.
```